# How to protect a client-facing json api against bot attacks?

Tags: security, web, single-page-application

***Disclaimer:*** I am a frontend developer without in-depth training in web security. Perhaps my question will sound trivial. Frankly, I hope it is — that means there is a simple solution. Please don't be angry.

I am working on a single-page web application that is architected according to a common pattern for modern web apps. Specifically, there is a web app itself that lives in the browser, a node-based "backend for frontend" that is responsible for rendering the app and for accepting ajax requests from it (most of which it then proxies to the "proper" backend), and then there is the "real" backend that is responsible for CRUD operations:

[image]

We want to make sure that requests coming to the "backend for frontend" have originated in the client-side app in the browser, and not in an attacker's script.

As a part of that task, I enabled csrf protection (using the [csurf](https://github.com/expressjs/csurf) library), but then it occurred to me that that cannot possibly be enough, because if the attacker makes a normal request using the browser, examines it in dev tools' network panel, and then copies cookies and headers (with the csrf token and the secret key stored in the cookies) from that request to his script, csrf protection will not be able to block such requests. At least as far as I understand how `csurf` works.

So, I am looking for a better way to make sure that requests are from the client app. Perhaps there is a way to combine the regular csrf-token-based protection with a timestamp to make sure that csrf token copied from request headers expires momentarily? Or maybe there are some other solutions? I am reluctant to invent my own security mechanism. Please advise?

*(I have found a [similar discussion](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/119034/how-can-we-protect-signup-apis-from-brute-force-registration) on security.stackexchange.com, but with few concrete recommendations)*

Comment: The attacker visits your site. Your web server sends an HTML page and script code to the attacker. Your "single-page web app" *is* the attacker's script: All you've done is send a few text files; all of the "front end" runs on the user's (i.e. attacker's) machine and is under the control of the user (i.e. attacker).

Comment: You can also add API rate limit like this library to your API https://github.com/nfriedly/express-rate-limit

Comment: @melpomene right :-) Now, to guard against suspicious behavior originating from the browser, we at least have CAPTCHAs. What I am asking about is what security techniques are available if the attacker is not using the client-side app directly, but is imitating its behavior with a script.

Comment: @azangru I'm saying there is literally no difference: Your "app" *is* a script that imitates the app's behavior.

Comment: @melpomene Ok, between an "app" and not-an-app that tries to behave like an app (e.g. bots that are trying to sign up, as discussed in the thread that I linked to), what options exist to tell them apart? Surely there are some? CSRF tokens, for example, kinda serve that purpose.

Comment: CSRF tokens defend against requests that don't originate from your own pages. They protect users from evil third-party sites. They do nothing to defend against evil users.

Comment: But if a python script sends requests to my site, these requests also don't originate from my own pages. Yet, if the writer of the script adds headers from a sample request from my own site to the requests sent by this python script, this will fool CSRF protection. So my question is how to guard against that evenruality.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing to say when replying to such questions is "why". You have not explained your threat model - i.e. what attacks are you trying to protect against, who will mount such attacks, and what is the impact of those attacks? As melpomene noted, an attacker can already use your client to do whatever they want. What are you trying to defend against here?

As was pointed out in the comments, in principle there is no way to achieve what you want: your backend-for-frontend server only observes traffic and a determined attacker can reproduce whichever traffic pattern your client Javascript uses.

With that said, you can make it *harder* for attackers to figure out how your service works, for example by using challenge/response mechanisms or complicated signatures on the data. But these "security by obscurity" techniques do not add theoretical security; attacks are still possible.

Another technique which is gaining momentum and may be applicable to your case is to look at the behavioral patterns of your callers to detect bots. There are several products that claim to do this, but I have not had personal experience with any such tool. You can Google e.g. for `detect bot traffic`. Again, these tools can be fooled in principle, but may add some practical security to your service.

Lastly, you could use a captcha for all operations in order to make sure (with some degree of confidence) that it's a human driving the app rather than a script.

You will need to rely on your threat model to understand what works for you.

Comment: Here is one of the biggest whys: it is very simple for new users to register in our app: one of the ways is just to submit a form with email and password. But we don't want bots to register, and we want to guard against brute-forcing passwords via login attempts. So in the browser, for example, we may add CAPTCHA for particularly sensitive forms, but that does not guard against signing up programmatically, by replaying the requests that the client app sent to its backend. It may be, of course, that instead of protecting the api we need to change the sign-up process to a more secure one.

Comment: @azangru Captcha might help here - see e.g. the [recaptcha documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/intro). Your backend-for-frontend server verifies the captcha response: this isn't client-side only. You still need to make sure that your backend (not backend-for-frontend) service isn't accessible to attackers. You can also secure the login flow e.g. by requiring interactive email verification or by rate-limiting sign up operations from a single IP address. Again, not bulletproof but can help.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP layer bot attacks are easy and common.
They can use tools like `curl` or python/nodeJS to simulate a real request coming from your web application. These are typically easy to defend against with a simple CAPTCHA with server-side validation. Web application firewalls (WAFs) are a basic and reactive tool used in this area too that can block based on static request values like IP/User-Agents etc.

More sophisticated bot attacks will rotate their Http headers and use many proxy networks to hide their true IP addresses. A WAF here would be completely useless. Also, most CAPTCHAs are easily bypassed when bots start using headless browsers (Puppeteer, Selenium) or simply purchase Catcha solver services (very cheap). See [2Captcha pricing](https://2captcha.com/) for instance.

You also have the more motivated bots who are usually incentivised by making money off their bot (sneaker or PS5 sniping bot for example). They are happy to use browser-based automation with residential IP networks to hide their activities.

In those cases, you'll need proper bot detection with client-side fingerprinting (to detect headless browsers) and server-side checks for rate limits and common attack patterns. Cloudflare, Shape (F5), Kasada etc offer these services but they can be costly for a simple web application that generates little/no revenue.